# "messages" from a deleted post? "inbox"?

Tags: support

One of my posts was deleted and I couldn't find the reason for closure or whatever the last comments made on the thread were. Am I missing a piece of functionality? Or is that information gone for good?

I see there is an "Inbox" in the upper left corner but I can't get it to load fullscreen.

Comment: Do you speak of one of your question, answer, or comment? In the latter case, I'm afraid we won't be of any help. Your last point has nothing to do with post history.

Comment: I cannot find any record in your info or activities page that indicates a deletion.  Do you know the thread that is involved?  What kind of "post" was it?

Comment: @chl It was a question. @whuber See @Dori's message below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked into this, and I can't figure out why or how [your question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12543/does-base-matter-in-ols-regression) was deleted either.

It has no flags on it, nor does it have comments about closing or deletion.

Consequently, I've reopened it: [Does base matter in OLS regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12543/does-base-matter-in-ols-regression)

Comment: Thanks @Dori. I noticed that some of the respondents disagreed with my premise (I think the question perhaps needs to be re-worded?), but especially when I was roundly shouted down for asking that an offensive (sexist) question on math.stackexchange, having my (perhaps confusing) question deleted on stats.SE seemed pretty strange. Thanks for allowing it a second life.